# Regular expression are not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
(@"^[^/;\\'-]+$)
```

Which not allowed apostrophe or hyphen in this regex.

Also I have to check that there will not allowed double quotes and double dash in this regex.

I want to modify this regex.

Comment: What's the purpose of your regexp ? And are valid samples of thing it should allow ?

Comment: Can you add the regex that you have tried so far and some samples on what you are trying to match/replace?

Comment: what is difference between hyphen and dash?

Comment: Suffered a lot? Any examples? Maybe try http://regexpal.com/ play with it, also you will find help here http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: does triple dash allowed?

Answer (score 0):

```
/["']/g
```

Will match double and single quotes

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ke9u5/)**

I do hope you're not using this to defend against sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JavaScript test() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) to check for occurrence of any one in the string.

Try `[-'\"]` to check for hyphen,apostrophe and double quotes.

Try `[-'\"]+` to check for 1 and more occurrence of these characters.

for e.g.:

```
/[-'\"]+/.test('a\'bc1'); // false
/[-'\"]/.test('a\"bc1'); // false
/[-'\"]/.test('a-bc1');  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are looking for this:

```
^[^"'-]+$
```

This matches a string that will not allow:

- double quotes
- apostrophes
- hyphens (dashes), and therefore not double dashes either (or triple etc)